# Endless loading on a website

Tags: javascript, css

I have a problem with a specific PC on a specific site that is running on JS.

According to the website's owners, the site runs only with Chrome due to compatibility issues.

In the Developer tools I've noticed that the endless loading caused probably due to this line:

> POST https://dc.services.visualstudio .com/v2/track 439 (Daily quota
>   exceeded)

I've tested it with a different PC and there does not have this error.

From my searches on the web, I've seen that this message was somehow linked to ASP.NET

I had extensions of ASP.NET on my "specific" PC and I've already removed all of them.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you cleared you Chrome cache and reset the browser settings?

Comment: While this may be ASP-related, it will be server-side ASP, and is very unlikely related to ASP software/plugins installed locally on your computer.

Comment: @music2myear Yes, I've already tried this.
If its only server side, why I have only a problem with a specific PC?

Comment: No, as in, if it is ASP, it is ASP on the server, and the ASP things on your computer have precisely nothing to do with the problem. What you need to do is try different browsers, clear cache, reset browsers, and possibly check for and install drivers and OS patches too.

Comment: So again if its ASP on the server side, so why I have this problem only on a specific PC?
I've tried already to switch and rest browsers, clear cache, tried already to update OS and install patches.
I can send a full "developer" log if it will be helpful.